# Sort by last name and first name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a small little problem. I am have a drop down list that displays all of our customers names. As of right now, the list is sorted by last name (A-Z). But for example, there are 250 people with the last name "Smith". What I need is a way that the last name of each customer to  stay the way it is but I need the first names to be listed alphabetically as well. Here is an example:

```
Customer #1 - Smith, Jean
Customer #2 - Smith, Allen
Customer #3 - Smith, Davey
```

What I would like is this:

```
Customer #1 - Smith, Allen
Customer #2 - Smith, Davey
Customer #3 - Smith, Jean
```

Here is how I am pulling the list now:

```
SELECT customer_id, first_name, last_name FROM customers ORDER BY last_name
```

Comment: What the data structure looks like, you are creating the list from?

Comment: what is your current sorting method (sql query probably) and what does your db table look like? You probably just need to add a second value to the `order by` field

Comment: You need to show the code that generates the list. If it is being pulled from a DB, you can probably do it with the database query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adjust your SQL statement, add the `ORDER BY` clause with the appropriate field names:

`ORDER BY last_name ASC, first_name ASC`

Answer (score 4):

Just change your `ORDER BY` clause to:

```
ORDER BY last_name, first_name
```